# Configure Logstash by environment variables instead of logstash.conf

Tags: docker, docker-compose, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

Im running a ELK stack in docker-compose. I'd like to configure logstash without the use of volumes. How can I configure the settings in logstash.conf with environment variables?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Take a look on how to [use environment variables](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html)

Comment: @leandrojmp yeah but I don't want to use the configuration file. I'd like to define the whole configuration as an environment variable

Comment: You will need to pass your config to the variable `CONFIG_STRING`, which will get translated to logstash as `config.string`, just check the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.6/docker-config.html#docker-env-config) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.6/logstash-settings-file.html)

Comment: @leandrojmp Thanks, that's what I was searching for! It's working now